# Pattern Matching for Country codes in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a requirement to filter out data based on the country codes . For example if the phone numbers are 
 +911234567891,+922234567891,+933234567893.
Now we need to dynamically create patterns to get the country codes for the phone numbers. Some country codes might be +91,+3581,+93 etc.

can you please suggest an approach

Comment: Why not have a trie and you just do pattern matching with your initial phone numbers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use maven repository [libphonenumber](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/3.5)

**Get CountryCode by local phoneNubmer** (example : +85595555555 -> KH)

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse("+85595555555", null);
String countryCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForNumber(phoneNumber);
```

**Get Country Fullname** (example : KH -> Cambodia)

```
String displayCountryName = new Locale("", countryCode).getDisplayCountry();
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. worked after adding the phonenumber library in my project.

Comment: Yes, It's ok. Thanks u :)

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how many countries you are excluding, it may be faster to create a text file/store and store the codes in an array, if not, the below approach could work.

This is more of a high level approach as you have not provided any context, i.e. input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.

One approach could be as per below.

1. Download a list of all countries and associated dialling codes (try here: https://datahub.io/JohnSnowLabs/iso-3166-country-codes-itu-dialing-codes-iso-4217-currency-codes#resource-iso-3166-country-codes-itu-dialing-codes-iso-4217-currency-codes_zip).
2. Read the above data into your java program and filter out any codes which are not to be excluded, this will basically be your exclusions list. (https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csvs-in-java/)
3. Write a function to iterate through each phone number, if there is a match then exclude - pseudocode below.

```
for each phone_number do {
   for each country_code {
      if(phone_number.contains(country_code) {
         do exclude phone_number
      }
   }
}
```